# How to force TCP window scaling using SSH?

Tags: ssh, networking, tcp, file-transfer

Inter continent data transfer's speed is maximum 2MB/s.

I checked and the SSH server of my server doesn't even use window scaling, and the window itself is very small, around 22KB...

```
Flags [S], seq 1433200120, win 29200, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 1451891061 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
Flags [S.], seq 3549718494, ack 1433200121, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4214039974 ecr 1451891061,nop,wscale 9], length 0
```

Server is 65535*9=**590 KB**

Window scaling is enabled.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling 
1
```

And I've already increase all the parameters to 25MB and 16MB minimum an default in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.core.wmem_max=25165824
net.core.rmem_max=25165824
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 16777216 16777216 25165824
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 16777216 16777216 25165824
```

I'm using Fedora 39 and RHEL 8, what can I do to force the SSH server to handle much more inflight data?

Comment: scaling 9 means 2^9 = 512

Comment: This does not look like an issue with the window scaling at your end. If your packet traces suggest this is the issue, then you should check the other end (e.g. AIX still defaults to disabling this the last time I checked)

Comment: How come? I set the min window at 16MB, I get 0.5MB... I really want to force a much bigger window to improve the bandwidth.